# Struggling to execute nested update query

Tags: mysql

I know 1-2 people have asked this question before but in my case that didn't helped me. What I'm doing is--
      I have written following query to update the table-

```
UPDATE tbl_query_master SET view_status=1 WHERE query_id IN (SELECT query_id FROM tbl_query_master WHERE view_status=0 ORDER BY query_date ASC LIMIT 2);
```

but it is giving me a following error

"***#1235 - This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'***". I have tried the following things-

1] I have execute inner query separately ***(i.e. SELECT query_id FROM tbl_query_master WHERE view_status=0 ORDER BY query_date ASC LIMIT 2)*** then it is giving me an expected result.

2] Also I have replaced inner query by hard coded values as "***(UPDATE tbl_query_master SET view_status=1 WHERE query_id IN(52,53))***" also in this case it is giving me an expected result. Thank You..!

Comment: @AlexGreg it is "5.5.33"

Comment: take a look at the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why don't you use join instead?

```
UPDATE tbl_query_master t1 
   INNER JOIN (
      SELECT query_id FROM tbl_query_master 
      WHERE view_status=0 
      ORDER BY query_date ASC LIMIT 2) 
   as t2 on t1.query_id = t2.query_id 
SET t1.view_status=1 ;
```

try first a `SELECT` to see if it's right

```
SELECT * from tbl_query_master t1 
   INNER JOIN (
      SELECT query_id FROM tbl_query_master 
      WHERE view_status=0 
      ORDER BY query_date ASC LIMIT 2) 
   as t2 on t1.query_id = t2.query_id;
```